# Can comment contain a question?

Tags: support, comments

Use case: 
I find a posting which explains my problem and an answer that relates.  However, I don't understand the solution's explanation.  Can I leave a question for his/her answer as a comment?

Comment: What would stop you from leaving a question in a comment?

Comment: Short answer - yes. Longer answer - don't use answers to ask for clarification on another answer, it is fine to ask in a comment.

Comment: If your asking for specific clarification within the scope of the answer and it's question; yes -- though there's no obligation for them to respond. If you're just asking a new, slightly related question; then no. Ask a new question.

Comment: I was asking a new question when I do not understand. Today I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36863159/java-sending-mail) and someone commented a link and said possible duplicate. It actually is not duplicate, because that question he commented is not a solution of my problem. Hence I wanted to ask if I can comment a question. Thank you all!

Comment: You can also edit your question to explain why exactly it differs from the proposed duplicate.

Answer (score 33):

**Posting questions in comments on questions**

If you have a question about a question, then feel free to leave a comment asking for clarification or improvement on the question. If it is your question, and someone posts a comment, do not hesitate to respond or ask a question of the previous comment. *Being attentive in comments on your own posts is very important*.

In general, it is best to avoid asking a continuation question or tangential question in a comment on a question. However, that is less common than users who post them on the answers themselves.

**Posting questions in comments on answers**

Preferably not, unless there is something in the answer which was incorrect or in need of change - in which case comments are fine or a clarifying "did you really mean to end your loop early on line 4?".

Asking questions as follow ups on answers tends to be a ["help vampire"](https://web.archive.org/web/20181124221026/http://www.skidmore.edu/~pdwyer/e/eoc/help_vampire.htm) trait which is frowned on here. Some users may not mind but overall it generally isn't considered to be polite.

A better route would be to identify the misunderstanding you have with the answer. Then attempt to look for a question which addresses that misunderstanding because it more than likely exists - this may require several different attempts at search phrases.

If you find an existing post, great! Hopefully that solved the issue. If not, and you are certain one does not exist, then craft your own. Ensure that in as small as possible you show a reproduction of the issue from which the misunderstanding arose (picture trying to answer your own question, is there enough context and example to provide an answer?), and include a link to the answer which sparked the misunderstanding.

Comment: If you have a question about an answer, and post it as a standalone, it's not wrong to put a comment with a link to ones question on the answer.

Comment: @Bergi - I agree

Comment: I agree with the above. However, it would be worth clarifying the distinction between requesting clarification of an answer when the answer itself is unclear (which should be a comment), and requesting some specific help applying an answer to one's own scenario (which may be a new question in its own right, as you explain above).

Answer (score 20):

**Yes!**

Requesting clarification is literally the purpose of comments.

Just be sure that you're not asking a follow-up question

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @DavidPostill's comment above.  As long as the comment is asking for clarification, rather than expanding the scope of the answer, it can be useful.  This often leads to edits that improve the quality of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I leave a question for his/her answer as a comment?

Yes, you can. If you still have difficulties to understand the answer given then you can leave a comment to the answer asking for more clarification on that part of the answer you are having difficulties to understand.
SE sites also provide discussion on chat so you can start chat (some reputation barrier over this feature)  to discuss further.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely should leave questions in comments if the answer to the question can improve the post.

If an OP asks a question and parts of the question are not clear, please question the parts that are not clear in comments, and hopefully the OP can edit the question to make it clearer.  New users, especially, tend to ask questions that are not always complete enough to answer.  This is how we get them to complete the question and teach them what they may be missing from a potentially good question.

If an answer is unclear, please feel free to question it.  Again, this is how we make sure that answers are clear enough for anybody that may come across them.

The exception is if your question is really a different question that should be standing by itself.  For example, on a php question, "How would I do the same in javascript?" is not a good question to ask (if you need to ask such a question, feel free to ask it as a new question and not as a comment).  Something like, "Why did you use a set here, when you need the results sorted at the end?" would be perfectly valid.